# C#: Send message to another socket from current active socket

Tags: c#, sockets

The server listener class starts to accept incoming connections from all IP's:

```
while (true)
{
    CommandManager cm = new CommandManager(s.Accept());
}

public CommandManager(Socket clientSocket)
{
    this.socket = clientSocket;
    this.networkStream = new NetworkStream(this.socket);
    this.bwReceiver = new BackgroundWorker();
    this.bwReceiver.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(StartReceive);
    this.bwReceiver.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void StartReceive(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    while (this.socket.Connected)
    {
        string s = dataStr.Substring(10);
        Command c = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Command>(s);
        CommandHandler.HandleCommand(c, clientIP, this.socket);
        this.networkStream.Flush();
    }
}
```

`CommandHandler` does different things depending on the command, and when a command is received (from a Corona SDK app) everything works great. The problem is when I need to send back a message after receiving a message.

First, if a player logs in I save that communication info in Communication class which saves the socket information:

```
Player.Player p = new Player.Player(cmd.PlayerID);
p.Communication = new ClientCommunication(clientSocket);
```

However if the command is "UpdateTable" I also need to send back the Table information to all the active players and this is where the problem occurs:

```
if (cmd.Cmd = Command.UpdateTable)
{
    //Do the updates
    //Send back the updates to the players                    
    Command c = new Command();
    c.Cmd = Commands.ReceiveTables;
    c.Tables = new List<Table.Table>();
    Table.Table t = Table.TableManager.ReturnTable(cmd.Table.TableID);
    c.Tables.Add(t);


    string command = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(c);
    command = command + Environment.NewLine;

    foreach (Table.Seat seat in t.Players)
    {
        try
        {
            Communication.ClientCommunication com = Player.PlayerManager.GetCommunication(seat.Player.PlayerID);
            Socket client = com.ReturnSocket();
            client.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(command));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }   
    }
}
```

I have verified that in `client.Send()` the port and IP as correct but I only receives a message back to the original sender (i.e. the player that sent in the messages receives the message but the other player(s) doesn't receive anything from the `client.Send()`).

Comment: How many Seats are in t.Players? Does the loop do all seats properly?

Comment: Yepp, I added a mbox that printed out a message and I got two pop-ups also printing out the different ports and it was all correct - the amount of popups (i.e. the amount of players), the port number and the IP (all IP's are local and on the same maching from the Corona Simulator)

Comment: Have you used a network sniffer to see that the messages are sent out to your clients?

Comment: One of the two messages to the clients contains information, the other message is empty (according to SmartSniff). I was wondering if it might have something to do with the messages blocking eachother? Like it needs to send them through ASync or running different threads or something like that?

Comment: A couple of issues I have with your code: 1. You're using a temporary buffer as your send buffer in the call to client.Send when you use the GetBytes function. I'm not sure how safe that is. 2. You're not taking the amount of bytes sent from your Send function. Is your socket in blocking / non-blocking mode? 3. Design wise, I don't like the way your Communication object exposes the socket. I think a better practice would be to wrap it with your own interface, but that is up to you of course.

Comment: Thanks @o_weisman. I will change it and implement a "heartbeat" function instead on the client side and request the updates when there is a change instead of sending back a response to all the clients. This way I don't need to expose the sockets and also it will work without any bigger modifications.